# Why do I get null `Authentication` as @Controller method parameter in `@WebMvcTest`?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-test-mvc

The context: I created a test annotation `@WithMockAuthentication` to populate test security context with an `Authentication` instance, much like `@WithMockUser` does.
The main difference being, in my case, the instance is a Mockito mock.

What I experience: As soon as I replace an actual instance with a mock, the `Authentication` instance provided as controller method parameter is null in annotated tests: in the `WithSecurityContextFactory`, if I replace:

```java
    public Authentication workingAuthentication(WithMockAuthentication annotation) {
        return new TestAuthentication(annotation.name(), Stream.of(annotation.authorities()).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    }
```

with

```java
    public Authentication bogousAuthentication(WithMockAuthentication annotation) {
        var auth = mock(Authentication.class);
        when(auth.getName()).thenReturn(annotation.name());
        when(auth.getAuthorities()).thenReturn((Collection) Stream.of(annotation.authorities()).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        when(auth.isAuthenticated()).thenReturn(true);
        return auth;
    }
```

Then I get NPE in the controller tests at

```java
    @RequestMapping("/method")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_AUTHORIZED')")
    public ResponseEntity<String> securedMethod(Authentication auth) {
        // Here, auth is null if Authentication is a mock
        return ResponseEntity.ok(String.format("Hey %s, how are you?", auth.getName()));
    }
```

I've created a [minimal sample to reproduce](https://github.com/ch4mpy/issue-8228). Run the test to see the failure.

I'm pretty sure I face a bug. Enough to create [an issue in spring-security project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8228), but it seems that Spring team team has no time to investigate...

[EDIT]
This last statement is uselessly offensive and completely wrong as the answer is provided by Rob Winch, who is a major member of spring-security :/ My Bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument for your [SampleController](https://github.com/ch4mpy/issue-8228/blob/0f30f0ef107422812faf2477523381148f5080fe/src/main/java/ch4mpy/web/SampleController.java#L23) is of type `Authentication` which is an instance of `Principal` and thus the [ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3ad42aa983bb49621254d2a6b251b0ed109fabdc/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.java#L163-L169)  will attempt to resolve the argument from `HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()`.

The [mock that you are creating](https://github.com/ch4mpy/issue-8228/blob/0f30f0ef107422812faf2477523381148f5080fe/src/test/java/ch4mpy/WithMockAuthentication.java#L67-L72) did not stub the `Authentication.getPrincipal()` method.

```
public Authentication bogousAuthentication(WithMockAuthentication annotation) {
    var auth = mock(Authentication.class);
    when(auth.getName()).thenReturn(annotation.name());
    when(auth.getAuthorities()).thenReturn((Collection) Stream.of(annotation.authorities()).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    when(auth.isAuthenticated()).thenReturn(true);
    return auth;
}
```

For that reason, `Authentication.getPrincipal()` is `null` and thus [`SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/71b4248fe63595548ca7ca663b5fe376daebf4c8/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/servletapi/SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.java#L144) returns `null`. Why does it return `null` when the principal is `null`? I cannot be certain the original intention as the [code was added](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/834f691) before I was a team member. However, it makes sense in Spring Security's model. `Authentication` can represent both an authenticated user and credentials used for authenticating. The [Javadoc of `Authentication.getPrincipal()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#getPrincipal--) states (emphasis mine):

> The identity of the principal being authenticated. In the case of an
>   authentication request with username and password, this would be the
>   username. **Callers are expected to populate the principal for an
>   authentication request**.
>
> The AuthenticationManager implementation will often return an
>   Authentication containing richer information as the principal for use
>   by the application. Many of the authentication providers will create a
>   UserDetails object as the principal.

The `null` check is to ensure that the `Authentication` is indeed representing an authenticated user.

To fix it you must stub out the `getPrincipal()` method with something like `when(auth.getPrincipal()).thenReturn("bogus");`. The change can be seen below and in my [pull request](https://github.com/ch4mpy/issue-8228/pull/1).

```
public Authentication bogousAuthentication(WithMockAuthentication annotation) {
    var auth = mock(Authentication.class);
    when(auth.getPrincipal()).thenReturn("bogus");
    when(auth.getName()).thenReturn(annotation.name());
    when(auth.getAuthorities()).thenReturn((Collection) Stream.of(annotation.authorities()).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    when(auth.isAuthenticated()).thenReturn(true);
    return auth;
}
```

Comment: Also, I steel need to reproduce, but I'm almost sure the Authentication argument is provided in webflux. Shouldn't the behavior be the same on both sides of the force?

Comment: I updated the answer to indicate why a getPrincipal check is performed.

Comment: I have a different understanding of the spec. `Authentication` is a (extends) `Principal`. Shouldn't "Callers are expected to populate the principal for an authentication request" be implemented with a check on `auth.getName() == null` (rather than `auth.getPrincipal() == null`) as this is the method specified in `Principal` interface and principal is not a `Principal` but an `Object` ?

Comment: I'd turn the question around and ask why would you have an Authentication where getPrincipal is null? I understand where you are coming from, but this is how Spring Security chose to map an Authentication object to Principal. Honestly, I'm not sure I would have chosen to do it that way, but changing it at this point is a bit out of question given the impact it would have.

Comment: I don't use `getPrincipal()` return value. Granted authorities are enough most of the time, sometimes, user name (Authentication.getName() should answer that) to retrieve user-details and if I need to use more of `Authentication` internals, then I use an implementation exposing something else than `Object`. So the only reason I'd use an Authentication where getPrincipal(), getDetails() or getCredentials() is not null is because I'm forced to by the framework (no use in my security expressions or methods body)